# How to extract the numbers from a text file

Tags: c#

After I made my button to open a window to select the file; I do not know how to extract the numbers from the actual file or from the stream called mystream.

```
Stream myStream;
OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();

openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "c:\\" ;
openFileDialog1.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*" ;
openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2 ;
openFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true ;

if(openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    if((myStream = openFileDialog1.OpenFile())!= null)
    {
//Problem here: How do i extract the numerical values from my txt file or the stream called mystream.
//  Insert code to read the stream here. 

        myStream.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Show your input file

Comment: You could use a `StreamReader` to read over `myStream`, call `.ReadLine()` and then `int.Parse`.

Comment: Btw, this is an exact copy from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog.openfile.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

Well, since we don't know your input format (as of the time I'm writing this), it's hard to tell you what to do precisely for getting the numbers out.

But here's the general gist for reading through each line of the file...

```
if(openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    if((myStream = openFileDialog1.OpenFile())!= null)
    {
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(myStream))
        {
            string line;

            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                // if it's one num per line, you can use Parse() or TryParse()
                var num = int.Parse(line);

                // otherwise, you can use something like string.Split() or RegEx...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: -1 Not an answer, just a wild guess. Remind me to cancel my downvote if OP accepts your answer.

Comment: @L.B It's a text file, so the numbers are bound to be in text format. `int.Parse` applies and so does this answer.

Comment: @Marlon So you are sure that every line contains a single int.

Comment: @L.B The question was "How do i extract the numerical values from my txt file or the stream called mystream" not "How do i extract the numerical values from my txt file *in this specific format*". This answer applies, since the OP needs to use a StreamReader, `ReadLine`, and `int.Parse`.

Comment: @Marlon What are trying to say? I declared that I will cancel my downvote if I the answer is correct. What do you expect me to do?

Comment: My two cents here. The MSDN states that StreamReader will call the Dispose method of the Stream object provided when the Dispose method of the StreamReader is called. So, perhaps, the first using is not needed.

Comment: @L.B. It is an answer, based on the information the OP has provided.  I mention in the comments other ways he could perform the int translation depending on format.

Comment: @Steve: True, though doesn't hurt in this case either.  I'll remove it.